# Issues with wordpress rewrite rules

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, wordpress-rest-api

I've been trying to get this rewrite working but I had no success. Just to explain, I want my wordpress site to go from 'localhost/wordpress/faces/foo' to 'localhost/wordpress/wp-json/showcase/foo'. By now I tried with multiple examples but the latest one is using non_wp_rules. Every time I go to the page it is redirected to the normal page system and then returning a "Page not found" error. Here is the code:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'dir_add_rewrites');

    function dir_add_rewrites() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $new_non_wp_rules = array(
        'faces/(.*)'       => 'wp-json/showcase/$1',
    );
    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules += $new_non_wp_rules;
    }

    flush_rewrite_rules(true);
});
```

and the .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^faces/(.*) /wordpress/wp-json/showcase/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also I have checked the .htaccess to make sure it is updated too.

Comment: What do you mean by _“is redirected to the normal page system”_?

Comment: On wordpress, normally, if you type an slug like "example.com/slug" index.php is going to look for that slug and pull out the page that corresponds to the permalink. My trouble is that I need to bypass that functionality and just do an straight redirect from "example.com/slug" to "example.com/wp-json/slug"

Comment: The Rule you currently have, only does an internal rewrite - if you want an external redirect, then this would also need the `R` flag. Not sure if that can be set with the WP functionality; if you don’t _need_ to do this via code, then it might be much easier, if you put the proper rule into the .htaccess file manually.